# How to fetch data on every element in an array using array.map method

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, reactjs, async-await

I want to fetch data for every object in an array and return an array of new objects with the previous and newly fetched data.I got stucked on getting my result array as my function is returning an array of resolved undefined promises.
I am using a flight search api thats using the ***apca*** function for fetching

```
export const searchApcaLocation = async (dataArr,setDeals) => {
    const promises = await dataArr.map(async item => {
        apca.request(item.destination);
        apca.onSuccess = (data) => {
            return fetch('http://localhost:3050/googlePlaceSearch',{
                        method:"post",
                        headers:{'Content-Type':'application/json'},
                        body:JSON.stringify({
                            cityName:data.airports[0].city
                            })
            })
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(imagelinkData => {
                const locationObject = {
                    data: item,
                    imagelink: imagelinkData.link
                }
                return locationObject
            })
            .catch(err => console.log('error on image search',err))
        };
        apca.onError = (data) => {
            console.log('error',data)
        };
    })
    const results = await Promise.all(promises)
    return results
}
```

can someone guide me please on what am I doing wrong?

edit:
as I am trying to fix it realized the problem is I am not returning anything in my map function but if trying to return the apca.onSuccess I am getting an array of functions

Answer (score 1):

just `return` is missing before fetch function. since you're not returning your promise result it's giving undefined.

```
export const searchApcaLocation = async (dataArr,setDeals) => {
    const promises = await dataArr.map(async item => {
        apca.request(item.destination);
        apca.onSuccess = (data) => {
            return fetch('http://localhost:3050/googlePlaceSearch',{
                        method:"post",
                        headers:{'Content-Type':'application/json'},
                        body:JSON.stringify({
                            cityName:data.airports[0].city
                            })
            })
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(imagelinkData => {
                const locationObject = {
                    data: item,
                    imagelink: imagelinkData.link
                }
                return locationObject
            })
            .catch(err => console.log('error on image search',err))
        };
        apca.onError = (data) => {
            console.log('error',data)
        };
    })
    const results = await Promise.all(promises)
    return results
}
```

Comment: just tried it but I am getting an array with undefined values instead of objects.
after console logging the steps I found out my results const is not awaiting for the promises const to fetch the data

Comment: @alexamirov can tell what is `apca` and add dummy `dataArr`. I'll share proper code block

Answer (score 1):

The issue in your case might be, that you are using async/await and then blocks together.
Let me sum up what is happening :

1) you await dataArray.map

2) within the map callback, you use the onSuccess method of apca

3) within this method you are using then blocks which won't await until you got a response.

At this point where you return the locationObject, your function already reached the return statement and tries to return results. 
But results are of course undefined because they never get resolved at all.

Also, keep in mind that your function returns another promise because you used async/await which you have to resolve where you imported it.

Cheers :)

Comment: Hey, just moved all my thens to async/await but got same issue where my function is returning undefined because its not resolving the results

Comment: Maybe the apca object is not designed to handke async await. Did you try to console.log(locationObject) right before you return it? Just to make sure you get a response.